# Determining if an array of NULL values is considered empty

Tags: php

I'm building an array to determine if I need to take an action. I am executing a query. The table has a `sent_date` field to determine if an email has been sent to a user or not. Once it has been sent to a user, that `sent_date` field is populated with `getdate()`. Here is how I'm building:

```
$sent_date_sql = "
    select ind_id, sent_date from profileemail
";

$results = dbExec($sent_date_sql);
```

I then build my array:

```
foreach ($results as $r){
    array_push($sent_date,$r['sent_date']);
    $query_count = count($results);
}
```

This all is working gloriously. My issue is when I go to check the `sent_date` array. The first time in the month that this script runs, ALL `sent_date` values are NULL. So my array looks like:

```
array(228) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
  [3]=>
  NULL
  [4]=>
  NULL
```

...etc.

Now I am going to try to evaluate `$sent_date`:

```
if(empty($sent_date)){
```

My `empty` condition never hits because the values of the array are all NULL. Is there an alternative way to achieve what I am trying to do? Should I be looping through my `$sent_date` array and evaluating each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!array_filter($sent_date))
```

`array_filter` removes all "empty" elements from the array. If all elements in the array are "empty", the result is an array with no elements (`array()`). An empty array evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow up two ways.

1. As told in first answer, you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). It excludes all negative, null, empty values from the array.
2. Modify your query, so that you don't need to work in php much.

   ```
   $sent_date_sql = "select ind_id, sent_date from profileemail where sent_date != NULL or sent_Date != '' ";

   $results = dbExec($sent_date_sql);
   ```